# Why does rerolling two dice change probability over setting a randomly selected die value?

Tags: probability, algorithms

I stumbled on a youtube video that defined the following problem:

> 2 dice are rolled.

> A 3 appears on at least one of the dice.

> Find the probability that the sum of the upper-most faces is greater than 7.

We assume that the 3 appears on the upper-most face of the die.

My initial thought was that the result would be 2/6, but the video explained that it's 4/11.

I wanted to roughly confirm that (and I did, that's not the issue), so I wrote a JS function to test it over a milion/bilion/x samples.

At first I was getting a slightly higher result though, and only upon fixing a logical "error" I was able to get the correct 4/11 result.

The error was that instead of rerolling both dices until one of them is 3, I was setting a randomly selected dice to 3 if neither of them was a 3.

Code before the change:

```
function testTheory(samples = 10000000) {
    function roll() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }
    
    let positive = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
        let rollA = roll();
        let rollB = roll();

        // Substitution
        if (rollA !== 3 && rollB !== 3) {
            const rollC = roll();
            if (rollC > 3) { 
                rollA = 3;
            } else {
                rollB = 3;
            }
        }
        
        if ((rollA + rollB) > 7) {
            positive++;
        }
    }
    console.log(`Positive: ${positive}, probability: ${positive/samples}`);
}
```

Prints: `Positive: 3887204, probability: 0.3887204` when called (numbers might differ slightly).

Code after the change (it's pretty much the same, only the lines next to the comment change):

```
function testTheory(samples = 10000000) {
    function roll() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }
    
    let positive = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
        let rollA = roll();
        let rollB = roll();

        // Rerolling
        while (rollA !== 3 && rollB !== 3) {
            rollA = roll();
            rollB = roll();
        }
        
        if ((rollA + rollB) > 7) {
            positive++;
        }
    }
    console.log(`Positive: ${positive}, probability: ${positive/samples}`);
}
```

Prints `Positive: 3638915, probability: 0.3638915` when called (numbers might differ slightly).

I do not understand however why is that changing the probability, in my head that's pretty much the same operation. I'd really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Knowing that a $3$ appears rules out many outcomes. This need not change the probability for some event , but usually this is the case.

Comment: In the first code, if both dice are different than $3$, then you randomly substitute _one_ of the values with $3$, which excludes the possibility of obtaining $(3,3)$. Hence, if you had to re-roll, you could only get _exactly_ one $3$, as opposed to _at least_ one 3.

Comment: @Bergson I see it now, upon fake-rerolling I was getting 1 less possible "negative" outcome, which was influencing the probability. Thank you!

Comment: Conditional probability that you get $5$ or $6$ on the other die given you got $3$ on one die is indeed $4/11$, as can be easily shown. You find it counterintuitive? Intuition can mislead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code, you are calculating

$$\frac{11}{36}\frac{4}{11}+\frac{25}{36}\frac{2}{5}$$

$$=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{5}{18}$$

$$=\frac{7}{18}$$

which is the probability the event happens (at least one three and then no threes), times the probability the sum is greater than seven ($35,36,53,63$ from $11$ and then $5$ or $6$ from a sample space of $\{1,2,4,5,6\}$), summed together.